# Launching the "Coded UI Test Builder" without creating a new Coded UI Test

Tags: visual-studio-2010, coded-ui-tests

The Coded UI Test Builder application in Visual Studio is very useful when hand-writing Coded UI Tests. It has an 'inspector' type tool that shows properties for a selected control, which makes searching for the control very simple.

At the moment the only way I am able to launch this tool is by going through the 'add new Coded UI Test' wizard. This launches fine, however it

- creates a new empty coded UI test
- closes down when I next run a test or start debugging in Visual Studio

Has anyone advice on how to launch the tool without adding a new Coded UI Test? Any other suggestions around inspecting controls with a hand-written Coded UI Test?  I'm working in WPF if it makes any difference.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

With a class like this one, right clicking inside the test method should give you a "Generate Code for Coded UI Test" -> "Use Coded UI Test Builder" option. It will still minimize Visual Studio, but it shouldn't create a new test method. There is also a keyboard shortcut: <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>\</kbd>, <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>

```
[CodedUITest]
public class MyUITests
{
    public MyUITests()
    {
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void StartMyTest()
    {
        //right click in here to get the context menu option
    }
}
```

Comment: You can also right click on the uitest file in Solution Explorer

Answer (score 9):

1. You can open Visual Studio command prompt
2. execute "codedUITestBuilder.exe /standalone"

Answer (score 5):

You can also right click the UIMap.uitest file in Solution Explorer and select "Edit with Coded UI Test Builder" No need for a Coded UI Test this way

Comment: I found the UIMap / 'recorded test' pattern didn't work very well at all. It wasn't able to find my dynamically generated controls and missed too many steps.

Answer (score 0):

Right click inside [TestMethod] and you will get the option for Edit with coded ui test builder.Click on that you can get test builder.
If you right click outside of [TestMethod] than "Edit with coded ui test builder" option will not come

Comment: You are not providing any new information for OP and the answer about the topic is already given. Your answer is not useful here.

Answer (score 0):

You can open coded UI builder by right clicking in between the Test Method or scripts and click on  "Edit with coded ui test builder".

Comment: Answering questions is good, thank you. But giving an answer that repeats what has already been written is not useful, specially on an old question. If you are answering old questions then it is best to add useful new information, or add details that give new insights on how to solve the problem.