# Why did my option of creating Coded UI tests disappear?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, coded-ui-tests

I am running Windows 7 Ultimate and Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate.  Somehow, in some way, the option of creating new Coded UI tests (right click on test project, select Add New Item, select Coded UI Test) disappeared from VS 2010.

Has anyone ever heard of such a thing?  If so, how did you fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Everything* in Visual Studio related to Coded UI Tests is context specific. For example, you can only find the Coded UI Test Builder link when your cursor is in a [class marked [CodedUITest]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6260522/launching-the-coded-ui-test-builder-without-creating-a-new-coded-ui-test). Create a new "Test Project" in your solution and see if the Coded UI Test comes back. If so, something happened to your other project file.